# How can I test whether Chromium is running inside sandbox

Tags: debian, security, chrome, browser, sandbox

I am using `Chromium` browser on `Debian Wheezy`. I read that `Chromium` is using sandbox to isolate its processes from the rest of the system and thus to increase security.

How can I verify that `Chromium` is indeed running inside a sandbox?

Is Chromium using sandbox by default, or do I have to configure it? When I start `Chromium` by clicking on the icon, and then look at the running process with `ps`, I see no indication that it runs in sandbox (i.e. no `--sandbox` parameter).

Comment: [Relevant description](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSandboxing) of Sandboxing on Linux. Posting as a comment since I'm unaware of how to answer your question about verification.

Comment: It seems that sandboxing is enabled by default, you need to run with --no-sandboxing to disable sandboxing according to the above link, as for how to test it... I haven't the slightest idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chromium sandbox is a separate program, `chrome-sandbox` (even for Chromium rather than Chrome). You'll see it running with

```
ps aux | grep chrome-sandbox
```

and you can see its relationship to the other Chromium processes with

```
pstree | less -pchromium
```

As mentioned by [Cestarian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73976/cestarian) the sandbox is enabled by default and can be disabled with `--no-sandbox` (but it's not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Within Chromium, visit `chrome://sandbox`.